# Math replacing natural language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, artificial-intelligence

Before reading any further. I ask yous to think creatively on this subject.

I was in shower and was pondering over A.I. (Strong A.I. both at human level and beyond human level) as I do from time to time and a quote from Neil deGrasse Tyson saying that math is the language of the universe (for us humans it is anyway) popped into my head.

Now I haven't found any articles or anything on the subject of perhaps trying to represent natural languages as math. A simple example would be to simply transform, let's say, this sentence I'm writing into a math formula.

Perhaps an A.I. can create it's own way to describe things with math, feelings, meanings, creativity, instead of using our clumsy languages. Then it truly would be the language of the universe.

Now, I am primarily a programmer. So I am asking you smart people, would this be possible? Please share your thoughts on the matter!

Comment: Did you forget you typed this on a Computer? Every time you type something a string of 0s and 1s are converted into sentence form. A compression algorithm may also be used.

Comment: @Zach466920 I'm thinking slightly more abstract than that. The word "sausage" in English and the word "korv" in Swedish are the same yet different, you get what I'm meaning? Also this could perhaps open ways which are more abstract such as describing feelings, creativity etc. I took this example of natural language as a first steeping stone as to say.

Comment: Google Translate ;) in all seriousness, language helps us describe what we are feeling. The actual words themselves are meaningless. You'd actually have to encode emotion into a mathematical framework, but now we've left math...I envision this being done "experimentally" by converting a brain into it's component parts and then modeling that with a computer. Then a frame work might be possible.

Comment: @Zach466920 Not entirely, "one plus one equals two" doesn't really describe a feeling in me (maybe warmth in mathematicians!). Words are used to describe "something" and as such so are formulas.

Comment: @Zach466920 Forgive me but A.I. does not only revolve around creating human like intelligence. There are several types of Strong A.I.. I apologize I maybe should of mentioned this in the original post.

Comment: You cannot express nonmathematical ideas with math, except perhaps poetically (not literally). Since (metaphysically speaking) we believe every possible state of the universe is some configuration of particles, or some quantum state of a wavefunction, or something along these lines - it makes sense to say "the language of the universe is math." It's not clear to me this is at all relevant to your question though! Anyway, you can biject the set of statements expressible in some language to a a set and then use elements of the set to store statements - like in Zach's comment about 0s and 1s.

Comment: @KarlMorrison "one plus one is two" definitely conveys a feeling from me to you. In my head I imagine, besides the symbolsI, trying to convey the concept of two objects is equivalent to the one of one object and another object. Math was founded on geometry after all. As to your point about AI, it need not copy human intelligence, but it's certainly wiser to use the method that works. For instance, if I'm not mistaken, neural networks, is a major method behind Google Deep Brain.

Comment: @anon But what if it can? It might not have to make sense for us humans (as we have natural language and) but for something that **can** read it. I feel humans **always** think that intelligence is exactly the way **we** perceive it. Something smarter than us might just be able to achieve such a thing such as using math to describe everything.

Comment: @Zach466920 And if you were blind from birth how would you covey one plus one equals two, you would not know of those symbols. Perhaps pressure sensation could represent the question? What I am trying to say that there are more ways of describing things, and perhaps math is one of them?

Comment: @KarlMarrison you just made my point. Ok using the word feelings vaguely, perhaps I should say thoughts, but the word thought has a connotation with actual words. All humans convey their own feelings, in one way or another, to the outside universe. However, they do it in different ways. Math/Logic, in this context, is a way to impose our wants on the inanimate world so it'll convey our ideas across distances too far for traditional communication.

Comment: @Zach466920 I agree the word thoughts is better fitting. I'll give you an example of something that helped get me into the question. http://www.no-mans-sky.com/ The game world is purely created through mathematical formulas created on fly. So, math is this context is capable of creativity. - I currently study A.I. and I like thinking outside the box, crazy ideas to bring up the most important thing which helps progress; **discussion**. I am familiar with ann's and deep learning. However trying to reproduce the human visual cortex is far from understanding what conscious is.

Comment: @Zach466920 I have also have an introduction into cognitive neuroscience as well. In short, the only area we know somewhat much of is the visual area, remember seeing those a.i. dreaming images? All about images. I wish to go more into actual conscious. I have no interest in computer vision as we do not need our eyes for our brains to function.

Comment: @KarlMorrison that's why I've been saying feelings, it's not bias towards sight. If I try and convey sound I imagine a sound not an image. I do agree though, creativity can be made from mathematical concepts. For instance I've used fractals to make music, and other people on google have too. However, I've never seen any algorithm successfully create and manage its own learning techniques, that's something that I believe is quite central to AI. (I do this for a hobby so don't think I'm an expert or something)

Comment: Can you write an essay on feelings or creativity if the only words you are allowed to use are "one," "two" and "three"? No, you can't. Nor is there any superintelligence that could. (You can't even form a sentence out of them, since you have no verbs!) Similarly, math cannot express ideas that it cannot express - this is tautological. It can't talk about things it can't talk about - that's an oxymoron. An omniscient may taxonomize all states of a physical system for which a vague human descriptor would apply - but the boundary of such a set of states would be very fuzzy and subjective.

Comment: Your ideas here are running up into many philosophical problems - things like the sorites paradox, or that of qualia and philosophical zombies or the chinese room paradox or "what is it like to be a bat?" and so forth. (Google these at your leisure.) Which makes this a question surely more suited for a philosophy forum. And you certainly have not given a good account of what you even mean by math describing things - it just strikes me as unintelligible nonsense. Even 'perfect intelligences' cannot make nonsense make sense. I am inclined to vote to close.

Comment: @anon Can one write an essay as so for humans? Perhaps not no, for something that thinks in a different manner to us, perhaps? We have not created superintelligence so I must disagree with your opinion that that it is not possible (we just don't know). Thank you for the links/terms, will read! I feel sorry for the feeling that you must vote for close, close mindedness is dangerous for the advancement of technology. I do hope you see more positively in crazy ideas in the future!

Comment: @anon About math describing things and not being clear. My intention was for people to perhaps use their imagination and creativity and themselves put forward an idea of what it could mean and/or be achieved, in the context on math and natural language. And I am inclined to say that unfortunately most mathematicians have a hard time thinking outside of the box.

Comment: Can a superintelligence make [colorless green ideas sleep furiously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously)? You seem to have this naive conceit that contradictions, absurdities and nonsense can become sensible when seen from the right perspective or with sufficient intelligence - this is only true in a loose, poetic sense. (I am strongly reminded of debates about the existence of Yahweh or Allah.) You want something, are not getting it from us, and you blame us for that. Perhaps revisit this question some years down the road and see if your blame is well-placed.

Comment: @anon I agree that **that** is nonsense and does not make any sense (the link). You took a very clear example in natural language (bound by rules which we humans invented). I was referring your "one" "two" and "three" in terms that a superintelligence itself decides for itself and which is not natural language (I think this is the confusion). The intelligence creates its own way to express thoughts, feelings, creativity (in my question I choose communication, way to express ones self). I am an atheist so drop the religion.

Comment: @anon 1) I have not demanded anything, I presume you know how stack exchange works. I ask, you don't have to answer. I do however appreciate a discussion 2) Blaming you? If you feel I am blaming you for something then I'm sorry I cannot help you with that.

Comment: @anon Just wow, please don't posit that you know how all of reality works. You are in no position to state what is and isn't sensible...you compare this to debates about God, are you aware the median scientific prediction for AI becoming smarter than humans is 2060? It's currently philosophical, but in many ways the analogy is not God, but rather comparing this to the scientific debate on the bomb in the 1930s, long before it was ever used in war. Of course definitely not suited for a math forum, seeing as none of the breakthroughs will come from this area.

Comment: Based on my reading, I was under the impression your question was about using math to express things like thoughts, feelings, creativity, not just about AI creating its own language for such purposes. Math simply does not have the vocabulary for that: we have vocab to describe sets, equations, categories and whatnot but nothing to describe feelings. One could certainly use math to model or simulate a being with thoughts, feelings, creativity (and possibly wind up creating real consciousness - who knows?), or be used to devise a system for storing and calculating with such things.

Comment: Lastly, what with the way you have vocally lamented us for not "thinking outside the box," for our "closed-mindedness," for us not being in the same "league" as your question etc. - I can't help but feel you are expressing your disappointment in our not meeting your expectations, no? @Zach466920 I don't understand what it is you're disagreeing with me about.

Comment: @anon I appreciate your first response, if only your other would follow suit. You say it is not possible, maybe it is? Your second post is atrocious. You are generalizing my words. I said to **one** individual that this question be out of that persons league. I feel pity for your attack on me. I am here for open ideas and to forward technology. Period. I am not here to beat my chest. As for expectations I was hopefully expecting a more content filled discussion where you experts could first understand the purpose of my post and react accordingly and then attack it.

Answer (score 2):

This is either trivial or hugely difficult, depending on exactly what it means to "represent" a language "as math". In both directions it seems like you should know more about this than we do.

I mean as I type this various English words are being represented as sequences of integers inside this machine - is that "representing" English "as math"?

On the other hand, using math to do anything interesting with a natural language, even just parsing it correctly, is hugely difficult (and again something someone would expect a programmer to know more about than a mathematician).

Probably you should ask Siri her opinion - I gather she's an expert on exactly this question...

Comment: I feel you and Zach are thinking too much about computers in the sense of binary. We have long used natural language and math before computers came into existence. Computers may use binary but binary on it's own does not describe the Earths trajectory around the Sun, a math formula does. I may be poor in my questioning, I chose to try and represent a natural language as math to simplify the problem. It seems to have confused yous instead (my fault).

Comment: If I knew you had no interest in the question you asked I wouldn't have bothered.

Comment: Arrogance and close mindedness go hand in hand. Perhaps the question is out of your league and that maybe for the benefit of my question and the community refrain yourself from answering anymore.

Comment: Perhaps. Then again perhaps not.